# How to manage multiple ball animations?

Tags: javascript

I have made a program that is supposed to make several balls move along a path. So far, I have only been able to make one ball successfully traverse the course because whenever I add another ball (from the array of balls) it begins to flicker and spasmodically disappears. I would appreciate any assistance in solving this problem.

[JS bin](https://jsbin.com/dezabaqimo/edit?html,output)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
 <style>
  * {
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
  }

  canvas {
   background: #eee;
   display: block;
   margin: 0 auto;
  }
 </style>
</head>

<body>
 <canvas id="Circuit" width="500" height="320"></canvas>

 <script>
  var dad = [];
  var canvas = document.getElementById("Circuit");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var bool = false;
  var dx1 = 2;
  var dx2 = -2;
  var dy1 = 0;
  var dy2 = 2;

  var memes = [{
   x: 0,
   y: 100,

  }, {
   x: 0,
   y: 100,

  }, {
   x: 0,
   y: 100,

  }, {
   x: 0,
   y: 100,

  }];

  function drawCircle(index) {
   ctx.beginPath();
   ctx.arc(memes[index].x, memes[index].y, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2);
   ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
   ctx.fill();
   ctx.closePath();
  }

  function draw(index) {
   if (index == 0) {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
   }
   if (memes[index].x < 490 && memes[index].y < 291 && !bool) {
    drawCircle(index);
    memes[index].x += dx1;
    memes[index].y += dy1;
   }
   else if (memes[index].x == 490) {
    drawCircle(index);
    memes[index].x += 1;
   }
   else if (memes[index].x > 490 && memes[index].y < 291) {
    drawCircle(index);
    memes[index].y += dy2;
   }
   else if (memes[index].y == 291) {
    drawCircle(index);
    memes[index].y += 1;
   }
   else if (memes[index].y > 291 && memes[index].x > 2) {
    drawCircle(index);
    bool = true;
    memes[index].x -= 2;
   }
   else if (memes[index].x == 2 && memes[index].y > 291) {
    drawCircle(index);
    memes[index].x -= 1;
   }
   else if (memes[index].x < 2) {
    drawCircle(index);
    memes[index].y -= dy2;
    if (memes[index].y < 100) {
     clearInterval(dad[index]);
     ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    }
   }
   ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
   ctx.strokeRect(2, 101, 490, 190);

   ctx.strokeStyle = "blue";
   ctx.strokeRect(2, 82, 40, 40);
  }


  setTimeout(function() {
   setTimeout(function() {
   dad[1] = setInterval(function() {
    draw(1);
   }, 20);
  }, 1000);
   dad[0] = setInterval(function() {
    draw(0);
   }, 20);
  }, 1000);
 </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I was playing around converting this to use `requestAnimationFrame` instead of `setInterval`. Not much for an answer, but you might get inspired. https://jsbin.com/suwinanipo/1/edit?html,output

Comment: thank you so much! Do you mind giving a quick explanation of what exactly you changed?>

Comment: I switched it to use a single timer as an event loop.

Answer (score 0):

The flicker happens when the second ball tries to render the frame. You have two sprites (animating things) clearing and drawing the frame. You also have multiple timers and when animating you usually want a **nextFrame** function that handles movement of the sprites and drawing the frame.

The **sprites** array is a list of things that need to be moved and drawn. I added some properties to the meme sprites so you can see that their **state** needs to be internal like with the "bool" value. Without that you end up effecting the other balls. You'll need to figure out how to remove sprites when they're no longer in play.

```js
var dad = [];
  var canvas = document.getElementById("Circuit");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var bool = false;
  var dx1 = 2;
  var dx2 = -2;
  var dy1 = 0;
  var dy2 = 2;

  var memes = [{
   x: 0,
   y: 100,
   color: "#0095DD",
   draw: drawMeme,
   move: moveMeme,
   vx: 1.2,
   vy: 1.5,
  }, {
   x: 0,
   y: 100,
   vx: 1.5,
   vy: 1,
   color: "#DD9500",
   draw: drawMeme,
   move: moveMeme
  }, {
   x: 0,
   y: 100,
   vx: 2,
   vy: 1,
   color: "#FF0000",
   draw: drawMeme,
   move: moveMeme
  }, {
   x: 0,
   y: 100,
   vx: 3,
   vy: 2,
   color: "#009999",
   draw: drawMeme,
   move: moveMeme
  }];

  function drawMeme(meme) {
   ctx.beginPath();
   ctx.arc(meme.x, meme.y, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2);
   ctx.fillStyle = meme.color;
   ctx.fill();
   ctx.closePath();
  }

  var sprites = [];

  function nextFrame () {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    var len = sprites.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      var sprite = sprites[i];
      sprite.move(sprite);
      sprite.draw(sprite);
    }
    ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
    ctx.strokeRect(2, 101, 490, 190);
    ctx.strokeStyle = "blue";
    ctx.strokeRect(2, 82, 40, 40);
    requestAnimationFrame(nextFrame);
  }

  function moveMeme(meme) {

   if (meme.x < 490 && meme.y < 291 && !meme.bool) {
    meme.x += dx1 * meme.vx;
    meme.y += dy1 * meme.vy;
   }
   else if (meme.x == 490) {
    meme.x += 1 * meme.vx;
   }
   else if (meme.x > 490 && meme.y < 291) {
    meme.y += dy2 * meme.vy;
   }
   else if (meme.y == 291) {
    meme.y += 1 * meme.vy;
   }
   else if (meme.y > 291 && meme.x > 2) {
    meme.bool = true;
    meme.x -= 2 * meme.vx;
   }
   else if (meme.x == 2 && meme.y > 291) {
    meme.x -= 1 * meme.vx;
   }
   else if (meme.x < 2) {
    meme.y -= dy2 * meme.vy;
    if (meme.y < 100) {
     // stop drawing this sprite
     meme.draw = function(){};
     meme.delete = 1; // for a cleanup function
    }
   }

  }

  nextFrame();

  function startMeme(index) {
    var meme = memes[index];
    sprites.push(meme);
  }

  setTimeout(function() {
    
    setTimeout(function() {
      startMeme(1);
    }, 1000);
    
    startMeme(0);
    startMeme(2);
    startMeme(3);
  }, 1000);
```

```html
<canvas id="Circuit" width="500" height="320"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you this was a very helpful solution. I greatly appreciate it.